# Trying to get a child check boxes to clear when the parent is unchecked

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot figure how to get the child check-boxes to clear once the parent one is unchecked. So for instance I check US and it opens up the Buildings like LA and etc... then if I check LA it opens up departments like Shipping etc..  I want it so they all can clear if the previous one is unchecked. I hope this is clear what I am trying to achieve. I will try and continue to figure it out and post the answer if I get it working.

criteria_form.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Checkbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h3>Checkbox Example with Javascript</h3>


  <input type="checkbox" name="us"><label 
name="us_lbl">US</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="building"><label name="bld_lbl">Building</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="department"><label name="dep_lbl">Department</label>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

js

```
<script>

   $(function () {
        $('input[name="building"]').hide();

        //show it when the checkbox is clicked
        $('input[name="us"]').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $('input[name="building"]').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('input[name="building"]').hide();
            }
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $('label[name="bld_lbl"]').hide();

        //show it when the checkbox is clicked
        $('input[name="us"]').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $('label[name="bld_lbl"]').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('label[name="bld_lbl"]').hide();
            }
        });
    });




   $(function () {
        $('input[name="department"]').hide();

        //show it when the checkbox is clicked
        $('input[name="building"]').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $('input[name="department"]').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('input[name="department"]').hide();
            }
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $('label[name="dep_lbl"]').hide();

        //show it when the checkbox is clicked
        $('input[name="building"]').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $('label[name="dep_lbl"]').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('label[name="dep_lbl"]').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwu9v46x/5)

Comment: The PHP is basically irrelevant to this.  Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: If you're interested, you can do the show/hide with CSS.  It won't help with your problem, but it's still nice :)

Comment: can you replace the PHP code with the generated HTML?

Comment: I'm using PHP code to pull the checkbox data from database. I guess for testing purposes I can change to html

Comment: @Donny That has nothing to do with the issue you're addressing in this question though.  Your question is only about checking/unchecking boxes based on another actions (checking/unchecking another box).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dwu9v46x/5/ here is fiddle I also simplified the code to html not php

Comment: so if you see in the example what I am trying to do is when you unchecked US I want the rest to clear  same with building I want the department to clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onCheckboxClick(elt){

  if(!elt.checked){

   var currentLevel = elt.className.split('-')[1]; // Returns the level of the current checkbox

   var childBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('level-'+(++currentLevel));

    for(var i = 0; i< childBoxes.length;i++){
      childBoxes[i].checked=false;
      onCheckboxClick(childBoxes[i]); // recursively go through next levels
    }

  }

}
```

So basically you would have this function on the click event of all checkboxes that have children.
and have the levels set as classes to each set of children
in your case:

```
   <input type="checkbox" onclick="onCheckboxClick(this)" name="us" class="level-1"><label name="us_lbl">US</label>
   <input type="checkbox" onclick="onCheckboxClick(this)" name="building" class="level-2"><label name="bld_lbl">Building</label>
   <input type="checkbox" onclick="onCheckboxClick(this)" name="department" class="level-3"><label name="dep_lbl">Department</label>
```

and what the function will do is extract the current level number, and gather all the children checkboxes in an array by adding 1 to the level, and then programmatically uncheck them.

You could alternatively define a custom attribute on your dom if you intend to use classes later.

Comment: still could not figure it out with your answer

Comment: @Donny you need to explain yourself, we don't write code at your place here, we just explain how things work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dtech29/phtxomks/16/ I ended up doing this not what I wanted but will work for now. I still need to figure how to get it to clear child check boxes  when I unchecked the parent checkbox

Comment: @Donny copy and paste the code in the appropriate sections of your fiddle, you will get the result for unchecking.

Comment: @Donny it didn't work because you are injecting the JS on page load, you need to have it ready or edit your function to perform the behavior of the onCheckboxClick function.